# How to setup api gateway integration to invoke step function?

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, aws-api-gateway-v2

I am trying to invoke step function and pass an input "id" from request path. When I invoke it, I get message

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to resolve property Input from source {\"id\":\"$request.path.id\"}. Please make sure that the request to API Gateway contains all the necessary fields specified in request parameters.",
```

How do I specify value for Input?

```
Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
DependsOn:
  - ApiGatewayHTTP
  - MyStateMachine
Properties:
  ApiId: !Ref 'ApiGatewayHTTP'
  IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
  IntegrationSubtype: StepFunctions-StartSyncExecution
  CredentialsArn: !GetAtt MyStateMachineExecutionRole.Arn 
  RequestParameters:
    StateMachineArn: !GetAtt 'MyStateMachine.Arn'
    Input: '{"id":"$request.path.id"}'
  ConnectionType: INTERNET
  PayloadFormatVersion: 1.0
  TimeoutInMillis: 3000
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above integration snipped correct syntax is

```
  RequestParameters:
    StateMachineArn: !GetAtt 'MyStateMachine.Arn'
    Input: "{\"id\":$request.path.id}"
```

However this does not work if the path parameter is Guid, or string.  One cannot invoke it just by making POST call such as POST `https://some.com/0943fsre300` for example, as it will throw an error, you have to wrap parameter in a path into quotes `https://some.com/"0943fsre300"`, you can also encode quotes.
After endless back and forth with AWS support they acknowledged that this a known problem, and that they are working on a fix.

Answer (score 0):

I think you make an error syntax in the RequestParameters input. To make it clear:

> Yours: Input: '{"id":"$request.path.id"}'
>
> Should be: Input: ""{"id": $request.path.id}""

You can refer to my example CloudFormation script:

```
  MyApiStepFunctionIntegration:
    Type: AWS::ApiGatewayV2::Integration
    Properties:
      ApiId: !Ref MyApi
      CredentialsArn: !GetAtt MyStateMachineExecutionRole.Arn
      IntegrationType: AWS_PROXY
      PayloadFormatVersion: "1.0"
      IntegrationSubtype: StepFunctions-StartSyncExecution
      RequestParameters: {"Input": "\"{\"id\": $request.path.id}\"", "StateMachineArn": !Ref MyStepFunction}
```

AWS official: [Set up request and response data mappings using the API Gateway console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-method-settings-execution-console.html)